# Simple way to receive SMS messages on arduino

Tags: api, arduino, ethernet, twilio

I have an arduino with ethernet shield, is there a simple way to receive and process SMS message text from the twilio api?

Comment: How would you want to receive an SMS without a GSM module?

Comment: Heres a way to do it by combining Twilio + Arduino + Pusher:  http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/08/diy-home-automation-using-twilio-powerswitch-arduino-and-pusher.html

Comment: I have to add that this way you are not receiving an SMS on an Arduino at all, but rather use a service that receives an SMS, and triggers a notification to an Arduino... (just nitpicking, the end result works the same...)

Answer (score 1):

Using an old cell phone and a SIM card you can easily receive messages without the need for the network shield nor gsm shield

http://www.power7.net/GSM_tutorial.html